# How to Calculate Execution Time and Get Command Exit Code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time, sh

I write a shell script and I want to get execution time of a command but I also redirect output of command to a file. Also, I need to get exit code of this specific command to use it in if statement. Here is what I have tried:

```
...
TIMEFORMAT=%R

log_file() {
  echo "$PROJECT_DIR/logs/$1_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).log"
}    

CODE_TIME=$(time sh -c "ipython -c "%run ./foo.ipynb" > $(log_file "log_file_name") 2>&1")

CODE_RESULT=$?

echo "Code_Result: $CODE_RESULT"

if [ "$CODE_RESULT" -eq 0 ]

    ...
```

According to documentation of `time`, it returns the exit code of the command but I also execute an `echo` command in function. So, anyone has an idea about how can I get exit code of `ipython` command? Thanks.

Comment: what kind of accuracy are you looking for in the timing ... nearest minute? nearest second? nearest millisecond? if 'nearest second' is sufficient then consider accessing bash's `$SECONDS` variable, something simple like: `start=$SECONDS; run-command; CODE_RESULT=$?; end=$SECONDS; duration=$((end-start))`

Comment: Or `SECONDS=0; run-command; CODE_RESULT=$?; echo $SECONDS`.

Comment: @markp-fuso @Cyrus I want to get in seconds but I'm using ShellCheck and it warns me about `$SECONDS` variable. So, I searched for an alternative and `TIMEFORMAT=%R` worked for me to get seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting in your sample call is unusual. I would expect that

```sh
sh -c "ipython -c "%run ./foo.ipynb" > $(log_file "log_file_name") 2>&1"
```

is translated to

```sh
sh -c 'ipython -c %run' './foo.ipynb > somewhere/logs/log_file_name_somedate.log 2>&1'
```

As for the behaviour of `time` wrt return codes, my `bash` (5.1.16) behaves like this:

```sh
$ time ls "I do not exist" > $(echo newfile) 2>&1

real    0m0,004s
user    0m0,004s
sys     0m0,000s

$ echo $?
2

$ cat newfile
"I do not exist": No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

And wrt to redirections like this:

```sh
$ capture="$(time (ls "I do not exist" > $(echo newfile2) 2>&1) 2>&1)"

$ echo $?
2

$ echo "$capture"

real    0m0,004s
user    0m0,004s
sys     0m0,000s

$ cat newfile2
"I do not exist": No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Therefore, I'd suggest you to try changing your call to:

```
CODE_TIME="$(time (sh -c "ipython -c '%run ./foo.ipynb' > $(log_file "log_file_name") 2>&1") 2>&1)"

CODE_RESULT=$?
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `TIMEFORMAT=%R` part of the script. So, it prints only real part. I will try and write the results. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Do you have any documentation about when to use `" ... "`, `' ... '`, `$( ... )`, `${ ... }` etc. I'm a bit confused about usages of these. Also, could you please explain why you used second `2>&1` part? Thanks.

Comment: @AHOME That's a very broad question. The first two are [String Literals](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) with the difference that with `"` expansions are possible (see below). The  third is called [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) which lets you capture and process the output of a subshell. And the last one, [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), is essentially how you access variables.

Comment: @AHOME As for the uses of `2>&1`. Here, both redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. In the first or inner case it is used to capture the output of the inner command (`ls` and its error message in my example), while the second or outer captures the output of the `time` command, which you wanted to be stored in a variable (compare to the case where I used it just once: the inner output was captured whereas the output of `time` was printed).

Answer (score 0):

Or just avoid `time` all together:

```
start=$(date +%s)
# run stuff, capture the return code
echo time $(( $(date +%s) - $start ))
```